# What is the derivative of the scalar product function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate the derivative of the function

$$g:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R: (x,y)\mapsto g(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n {x_iy_i}$$

at $(a,b)$. By definition, this derivative is a linear function $L:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ so that

$$g(x,y)-g(a,b) = L(x-a,y-b) + o(x-a,y-b)$$
where $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{o(x-a,y-b)}{\|(x-a,y-b)\|}=0$

If $x$ and $y$ are represented by column vectors then $L$ must be row vector of length $2n$.
Let be $L=(l_1,l_2)$ where $l_1$ and $l_2$ represens row vectors of length $n$.Then

$$L(x-a,y-b) = (l_1,l_2)(x-a,y-b)= g(l_1,x-a)+g(l_2,y-b)=g(l_1,x)-g(l_1,a)+g(l_2,y)-g(l_2,b)$$

but I don't see how to determine $l_1$ and $l_2$ from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B:V \times W \to Z$ be a bilinear map between finite-dimensional normed spaces. Given $x,h \in V$ and $y,k\in W$, we have that $$B(x+h,y+k) = B(x,y) +{\color{blue}{B(h,y)+B(x,k)}}+{\color{red}{B(h,k)}}.$$
Since $$0\leq \frac{\|{\color{red}{B(h,k)}}\|}{\|(h,k)\|} \leq \frac{\|B\|\|h\|\|k\|}{\sqrt{\|h\|^2+\|k\|^2}} \to 0$$as $(h,k)\to (0,0)$, we conclude that $$DB(x,y)(h,k)={\color{blue}{B(h,y)+B(x,k)}}.$$Note that even when $V=W$, $B$ does not need to be symmetric for the product rule to work. A similar formula holds for (vector-valued) multilinear maps.

If $B = \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product in $\Bbb R^n$ as you have there, then the derivative at a point $(x,y)$ is the linear map $L$ given by $$L(h,k)=\langle h,y\rangle + \langle x,k\rangle.$$

Comment: That is, in my notation, $l_1=b$ and $l_2=a$. Thank you! I clearly started from the wrong side. I like your color letters very much! They make the reading very easy.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! (Btw, you can click on "edit" here to see the source code for how I made the colors -- but they should be used sparingly... I have seen people go trigger-happy with colors and make their answer become an unreadable rainbow)

Answer (score 2):

Fix a point $(a,b)\in \Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n$ and let $(h,k)\in\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n$. Then,
\begin{align}
g\left((a,b)+(h,k)\right)&=g(a+h,b+k)\\
&=g(a,b)+g(a,k)+g(h,b)+g(h,k)
\end{align}
Define $L:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ as $L(h,k):=g(a,k)+g(h,b)$. Then, $L$ is a linear transformation and the above equation shows that
\begin{align}
g((a,b)+(h,k))-g(a,b)=L(h,k)+g(h,k)
\end{align}
We can show the remainder term $g(h,k)$ is small by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
\begin{align}
\frac{|g(h,k)|}{\|(h,k)\|}\leq \frac{\|h\|\cdot\|k\|}{\|(h,k)\|} = \frac{\|h\|}{\|(h,k)\|}\cdot \|k\|\leq 1\cdot \|k\|=\|k\| \leq \|(h,k)\|
\end{align}
and clearly the RHS (and thus the LHS) approaches $0$ as $(h,k)\to (0,0)$. Thus, the inner product $g$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ with $Dg_{(a,b)}=L : (h,k)\mapsto g(a,k)+g(h,b)$.

If you were to represent the linear transformation $Dg_{(a,b)}=L$ as a $1\times (2n)$ matrix relative to the standard basis $\{(e_1,0),\dots, (e_n,0),(0,e_1),\dots, (0,e_n)\}$ on $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n$, where $e_i=(0,\dots, 1,\dots 0)\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and the basis $\{1\}$ on $\Bbb{R}$, then we get
\begin{align}
[L]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
L(e_1,0) & \cdots &L(e_n,0)&L(0,e_1)&\cdots L(0,e_n)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & \cdots & a_n & b_1 & \cdots &b_n
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

---

**Generalization.**

As a side remark, the calculation of the derivative of $g$ is not special to the inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$. More generally, if you take any finite-dimensional real vector spaces $V,W,X$ and a bilinear (not-necessarily symmetric) mapping $g:V\times W\to X$, then an almost identical calculation will show $g$ is differentiable at every point $(a,b)\in V\times W$ and that for all $(h,k)\in V\times W$, $Dg_{(a,b)}(h,k)=g(a,k)+g(h,b)$. The only subtlety in the more general setting is that we have to show the remainder term $g(h,k)$ is small, so for this one has to use the fact that all bilinear maps are bounded in the sense that there exists a $C>0$ such that for all $(h,k)\in V\times V$, we have $\|g(h,k)\|_X\leq C\|h\|_V\cdot \|k\|_W$.

This actually works more generally for multilinear maps:

> If $V_1,\dots, V_n,W$ are finite-dimensional real/complex normed vector spaces and $g:V_1\times \cdots\times V_n\to W$ is a multilinear map, then $g$ is differentiable at every point $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in V_1\times \cdots \times V_n$, and for every $h=(h_1,\dots, h_n)\in V_1\times\cdots \times V_n$, we have
> \begin{align}
> Dg_a(h)&=\sum_{i=1}^ng(a_1,\dots, a_{i-1}, h_i, a_{i+1},\dots a_n)
> \end{align}

The intuitive way of thinking about this theorem is that multilinear maps are like "products", so $g(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ means the "product with respect to $g$" of the elements $x_1\in V_1,\dots x_n\in V_n$. So, the derivative of a product is of course very simple: differentiate each thing one by one keeping all others fixed, so symbolically:
\begin{align}
D(x_1\cdots x_n)&= \sum_{i=1}^nx_1\cdots Dx_i\cdots x_n\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where as I mentioned, the "product" $\cdot$ really means with respect to $g$, and here $Dx_i$ really means the derivative of the canonical projection function $x_i:V_1\times\cdots \times V_n\to V_i$, so $(*)$ written more properly is
\begin{align}
Dg&=\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_1,\dots, Dx_i, \dots, x_n)
\end{align}
which is a suppressed way of saying that if we calculate derivatives at a point $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ and apply it to the displacement $h=(h_1,\dots, h_n)$, then
\begin{align}
Dg_a(h)&=\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_1(a),\dots, (Dx_i)_a(h),\dots, x_n(a))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ng(a_1,\dots, h_i, \dots, a_n),
\end{align}
which is of course what I wrote in the highlighted blocktext. Hopefully this multitude of ways of presenting the product rule (and the way to interpret the extremely condensed notation) is helpful.

---

**Examples**

As some examples, suppose $V=M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ and $g:V\times V\to V$ is matrix multiplication: $g(A,B)=A\cdot B$. This is a bilinear operation, so for any $(A,B),(h,k)\in V\times V$, we have
\begin{align}
Dg_{(A,B)}(h,k)&=g(A,k)+g(h,B)=A\cdot k+ h\cdot B
\end{align}
Notice here the ordering is important. The condensed way of writing this equation is
\begin{align}
D(A\cdot B)&=A\cdot (DB) + (DA)\cdot B
\end{align}
(or sometimes people use a lower case $d$, so $d(AB)=A\cdot dB + (dA)\cdot B$).

For another example, let $V=\Bbb{R}^n$ and consider the determinant as a multilinear function of the columns of a matrix $\det:V^n\to\Bbb{R}$. Then,
\begin{align}
D(\det)_A(H)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\det(a_1,\dots, h_i,\dots a_n)
\end{align}
where $A=(a_1 \quad \cdots \quad a_n)$ and $H=(h_1\quad \cdots \quad h_n)$ are the columns of $A$ and $H$.

Comment: +1 for the Cauchy-Schwarz explanation.